# Android GCM (push notification): device doesn't receive notification if application is stopped

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I use push notification (GCM) in my Android project.

According to GCM tutorial I implemented broadcast receiver and registered it in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

This kind of broadcast receivers should receive messages even if my app is closed (not only if my app is in background but even if it was force stopped).

But it doesn't work as I expect. `onReceive()` method isn't being called if the app is closed. It seems that my understanding of broadcast receivers is correct and the problem is in my expectations about GCM.

One of the possible reasons is that google server doesn't even send a notification to the device if  the app is closed. So, is it correct that my app can receive a message (and `onReceive()` method will be invoked in broadcast receiver) only if it's running or in  background (but not closed)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a same problem and I don't get the answer. did you solve it?

Comment: If you want to simulate your app closing normally (kind of), on your device, under developer options, choose 'Do Not Keep Activities'. Then whenever one of your activities enters the background it'll be closed. But your Broadcast Receiver will keep running

Comment: @Fraser you're right, but an application's stopped state is not the same as an Activity's stopped state.

The system manages those two stopped states separately (http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> This kind of broadcast receivers should receive messages even if my app is closed (not only if my app is in background but even if it was force stopped).

If a user force-stops your app from Settings, your code will **never ever run again**, until something manually runs one of your components, typically the user manually launching an activity (as of Android 3.1). Hence, if the user force-stops your app from Settings, you will not receive GCM messages on newer devices/emulators.

> So, is it correct that my app can receive a message (and onReceive() method will be invoked in broadcast receiver) only if it's running or in background (but not closed)?

There is no concept of "closed" in Android from an application standpoint. If, by "closed", you mean "has no running process, where the last process was terminated normally", then yes, you should receive GCM messages and other broadcasts. But, again, force-stop is not "terminated normally".

Comment: I just tested this using the [airbop-client](http://github.com/indigorose/airbop-client) and I can confirm that the onReceive() method was not called after the app was force stopped. I see a logcat entry for the c2dm.intent.RECEIVE tagged with GTalkService showing result=CANCELLED.

Comment: Does it exist a documentation from android about "force close" ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just sent an email after force stopping(from settings) gmail app and still got notification. "If a user force-stops your app from Settings, your code will never ever run again" How did Gmail send a notification?

Comment: @SeshuVinay: You ran Gmail, and it sent your email. Apps will run when manually invoked after being force-stopped, but they will not respond to things like broadcasts.

Comment: @CommonsWare No. I sent email from desktop. And I am sure gmail app wasn't running. Because Force stop button got disabled after I pressed it once. So no process was running.

Comment: Just to make sure, I did this again. Force stopped Gmail app, Sent email from desktop, and got notification. BTW I tested this in Nexus 7(2012) device. Gmail version: 5.0.1(1642443)

Comment: Same happened with Inbox app. I dont know if I am missing something.

Comment: @SeshuVinay I too am facing the same problem , I am just curious as to whether you got the answer or not .This is the same case with watsapp too.

Comment: No. I still didn't get any solution.

Comment: I think it's only about having a process or not and it doesn't matter if it's forced to be stopped or system decided to stop it to free up space.

Comment: @Seshu Vinay Google might have tweaked their push handling system to notify Gmail and Inbox, using the FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag. By default, you can't wake up an app that has been forced stopped. But if you add this flag to your intent, it should work. See:  http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html#launchcontrols . If you test it, I'm interested.

Answer (score 3):

According to Francesco Nerieri in [this android-gcm thread](https://groups.google.com/group/android-gcm/tree/browse_frm/month/2012-08/7e74aab31da818e1?rnum=11&lnk=nl&pli=1):

> So if you force stop the app, the intended behavior for ICS is for the
>   app to not receive the message.  In JB this means that GCM will also
>   unregister the app, this is an  unfortunate behavior and we are
>   working to change this (the unregister  part in JB).

Comment: They seem to have worked it out since. I tested sending a push to a forced close app and GCM responds '"success":1,"failure":0'. When the app is  uninstalled, then it reponds that the registrationId is obsolete and should be unregistered (from your application server).

Comment: @John: Sucess: 1 means push is delivered to your device. If you connect your device to android studio, and check Android monitor, you will see something like:    W/GCM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) it says that :

> An Android application on an Android device doesn't need to be running
>   to receive messages. The system will wake up the Android application
>   via Intent broadcast when the message arrives, as long as the
>   application is set up with the proper broadcast receiver and
>   permissions.

Check your broadcast receiver implementation and permissions.

Comment: The docs only say "Wake up" which to me implies an app is "sleeping" or in the background. But when you force close an app it has no running process to "wake up", it needs to be started.