# PhoneGap Build push notifications: Android pushes do not work when the app is closed

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I have implemented a push notifications plugin for PhoneGap Build, waited for it for so long

https://build.phonegap.com/blog/introducing-genericpush-plugin

However I'm having issues with the Android app not running in the background. Push notifications are not received when I close the app. Everything is fine when the app is running. Has anyone tried it with Android? Are there any fixes that need to be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not something related to the GenericPush plugin itself.
It's something related to the way Android manages apps. If your user manually closes the app, it means that he doesn't want to receive messages anymore. This is why even the GCM BroadcastReceiver is stopped and the device doesn't receive the notifications.

Here's some useful links:

- [Android GCM google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topicsearchin/android-gcm/after$3A2012$2F08$2F01$20before$3A2012$2F08$2F31/android-gcm/MqVlA3Sj26c)
- [Similar question, related only to Android (native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073449/android-gcm-push-notification-device-doesnt-receive-notification-if-applicat)