# GCM BroadcastReceiver fired only when app is running or running at background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented GCM service and it all works fine but when I'm supposed to recieve a notification after I closed the app (By long click at home button and then at the garbage icon - Galaxy S III), I don't recieve it.

Here's my **Manifest.xml**:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.proj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.proj.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.proj.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/projicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.proj.FbActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
          <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="APIKEY"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"></activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.proj.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.proj" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.example.proj.GcmIntentService" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if by closing the app by the way I did kills the app proccess or it still should be running at the background and recieve those masseges.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android GCM (push notification): device doesn't receive notification if application is stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073449/android-gcm-push-notification-device-doesnt-receive-notification-if-applicat)

Comment: I've seen that question, but as far as I know and I've read, this type of closing should not close background processes / services that are running. That's why I pointed to this specific way and not terminating processes by going to setting etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I found out I made a mistake in the manifest file:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

should be:

```
<permission android:name="<your app package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<your app package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

where the app package is the package that contains the class that extends [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) (and should be pointed in the manifest file).

After fixing this, I've been able to force close my app and still receive push notifications via GCM.

Comment: this doesn't solved my issue. Can u help me? For which packages shouls i replace the package name with my package name? only for permission.C2D_MESSAGE?