# Receive notification when app closed

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I used onesignal to send notification to my app. The app work perfect when I send notification and its open. Unfortunately the app not receive notification when it closed even I set broadcast receiver.

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
 <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentService" />
    <service
        android:name="com.onesignal.SyncService"
        android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

Comment: Please check this answer similar to your question  [How to get android notifications when app was closed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741875/how-to-get-android-notifications-when-app-was-closed)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the receiver class extend WakefulBroadcastReceiver and add the following lines in your manifest :

```
<receiver android:name=".YOUR_RECEIVER_CLASS"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/> 
    <category android:name="com.example.gcm"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
```

to GcmBroadcastReceiver

And

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

should be

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    <permission android:name="<your app package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<your app package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</receiver>
```

depends on [GCM BroadcastReceiver fired only when app is running or running at background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707904/gcm-broadcastreceiver-fired-only-when-app-is-running-or-running-at-background)