# Is it possible to receive push notifications after force stop on android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-cloud-messaging

I develop my application with ionic framework and phonegap-plugin-push. After force stop application does not receive push notifications even in notification bar. Is it possible to fix it? Some messengers such as Telegram  continue to receive notifications after force stop.

Comment: Take a look to this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313539/push-notifications-when-app-is-closed. You have to add other listeners like service or widjet in you apk.

Comment: You should be receiving the push notifications just fine. If you're not, this is not a normal behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android GCM (push notification): device doesn't receive notification if application is stopped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073449/android-gcm-push-notification-device-doesnt-receive-notification-if-applicat)